# moq SetupSequence with queue only executing first time

Tags: c#, unit-testing, queue, moq

I am trying to make a mock dynamically with a loop that returns values based on a queue. The code used is as follows(Got it from another answer on stackoverflow).

```
var numberQueue = new Queue<int>(new[] { 4, 8, 16, 43});
var mock = new Mock<ITest>();
mock.SetupSequence(x => x.GetNumber()).Returns(numberQueue.Dequeue);

int x1 = mock.Object.GetNumber(); // expected: 4 actual: 4 
int x2 = mock.Object.GetNumber(); // expected: 8 actual: 0
int x3 = mock.Object.GetNumber(); // expected: 16 actual: 0
int x4 = mock.Object.GetNumber(); // expected: 32 actual: 0

x1.Should().Be(4); // passes
x2.Should().Be(8); // fails
x3.Should().Be(16); // fails
x4.Should().Be(32); //fails
```

The first one works fine but after that everything is 0. I am trying to get it running in this way because I want to be able to dynamically setup a mock for an IDataReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fix your problem, let me show you the three most basic ones.

#### Option #1

Use `Setup` instead of `SetupSequence`

```
mock.Setup(x => x.GetNumber())
    .Returns(numberQueue.Dequeue);
```

After this change your test will fail at the `x4.Should().Be(32)` line because `x4` is 43.

#### Option #2

Use `SetupSequence` with multiple `Returns` calls

```
mock.SetupSequence(x => x.GetNumber())
    .Returns(numberQueue.Dequeue)
    .Returns(numberQueue.Dequeue)
    .Returns(numberQueue.Dequeue)
    .Returns(numberQueue.Dequeue);
```

#### Option #3

```
mock.SetupSequence(x => x.GetNumber())
    .Returns(4)
    .Returns(8)
    .Returns(16)
    .Returns(43);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. The x4 error was an error when I took over the code to stackoverflow. But option 1 works, thank you!

Comment: @miquel09 I assumed the same that it was just a copy-paste issue :)